# Looking for something related to continued fractions but with a very different "algorithm" I once saw in a book

Tags: approximation, fractions

Years ago I saw a calculation technique that would with each iteration yield the next best fractional approximation of a decimal number. I was intrigued at the time, and have several times in the years since tried to find what book that was in (I thought it was in a book I owned, but can't find it now,) and I have searched several times on the Internet, and read many sites and watched videos about "continued fractions" but have never seen anything that looked like that technique.

I have certainly learned a lot about continued fractions and find them interesting, but the technique I am looking for looked very different, and did not yield the usual bracketed list of integers, but rather a series of plain looking fractions, each one a closer approximation than the previous. You could stop when the fraction was accurate enough and not to hard to remember.

If I recall correctly, you start with a decimal number and wrote the first fraction approximation, then with a bit of arithmetic (written above and or below it) you would have the next better approximation with of course a bigger denominator (and numerator.) You could continue until you found one that was as close as you wanted, or until the fraction was the exact value of the decimal number.

Now I don't remember if that presentation was called "continued fractions" or was just an arithmetic book from the early 1900's. I'm pretty sure it was an old book. And it seems obvious to me that the underlying principal was the same as "continued fractions."

Has anyone seen it?

Comment: I wonder whether the book you had was G Chrystal, Textbook of Algebra, Volume Two? The 1st edition was published in 1889. I have the 7th edition, published by Chelsea in 1964. Chapter 32, Sections 12 to 16, deal with "Closest commensurable approximations of given complexity" (pages 444 to 452, in my edition). Chrystal does use continued fractions. A pdf might be available via https://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupid?key=olbp36404

Comment: So, have you had a look at Chrystal?

Comment: Yes, I looked at it a little, but will get back to it later. I did play with the lemma on page 444 to test it quickly, and found it true, which I thought was interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Making any progress, Harvey?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I did write a program using BIGNUM library to play around with the algorithm as you outlined in your answer, and learned some interesting things. I'm on to other stuff for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We're going to build this table:
$$
\matrix{&&a_0&a_1&a_2&\dots\cr p_{-2}=0&p_{-1}=1&p_0&p_1&p_2&\dots\cr
q_{-2}=1&q_{-1}=0&q_0&q_1&q_2&\dots\cr}
$$
Let $x$ be your decimal. We take $a_0=[x]$ (where $[y]$ means the integer part of $y$, the greatest integer not exceeding $y$), $x_1=(x-a_0)^{-1}$ and $a_i=[x_i]$, $x_{i+1}=(x_i-a_i)^{-1}$. Also, $p_i=a_ip_{i-1}+p_{i-2}$ and $q_i=a_iq_{i-1}+q_{i-2}$. Then your increasingly good approximations are $p_0/q_0,p_1/q_1,p_2/q_2,\dots$.

For example, let $x=1.3862$. Then $a_0=1$, $x_1=(.3862)^{-1}=2.5893$ (to four decimals), $a_1=2$, $x_2=(.5893)^{-1}=1.6969$, $a_2=1$, $x_3=(.6969)^{-1}=1.4349$, $a_3=1$ and so on, so our table is
$$
\matrix{&&1&2&1&1&\dots\cr 0&1&1&3&4&7&\dots\cr
1&0&1&2&3&5&\dots\cr}
$$
and our approximations are $1,1.5,1.3333,1.4,\dots$.

The relation to continued fractions is that the $a_i$ are the partial quotients in the continued fraction for $x$.

Comment: Note that eventually roundoff error can make this go haywire, so if your $x$ is a terminating decimal, it may be better to work with fractions than decimals. $1.3862=13862/10000=1+(1931/5000)$, $5000/1931=2+(1138/1931)$, $1931/1138=1+(793/1138)$, $1138/793=1+(345/793)$, and so on.

Comment: I think perhaps this is kind of half way there. The working out of the process had no letters with subscripts at all, only numbers, and a relatively easy way of doing the arithmetic above and below the line of better and better fractions. So I see that your fractions 1/1, 3/2, 4/3, 7/5 are the correct fractions, but it seems much more confusing to see quite where they come from. For example, I don't see the integer 7 anywhere else. Where did it come from to make 7/5? I think your added comment may be applicable, but again, where does the 7 come from?

Comment: Okay, after studying it more I see how it works, and I'm quite sure this is doing the same thing, but what I remember really looked easier. But that was quite a few years ago. I would like to find that method again.

Comment: Thank you for this. The down vote was not me; my up vote got it back to 0. Once I really saw what you had here, I saw the similarity to the way the Fibonacci sequence is generated by always adding the two previous numbers. Now I see that indeed that is exactly a special simplified case of this method for approaching phi because for [1, 1, 1, 1, ...] all the inverting of fractions can go away and because of the initial 0 1 and 1 0 for p and q you simply get the Fibonacci sequence for p and for q delayed by one iteration. Thus the fractions are ever better values for phi. Very cool!

Comment: Another way to present this is as the Euclidean algorithm. $13862=1\times10000+3862$; $10000=2\times3862+2276$; $3862=1\times2276+1586$; $2276=1\times1586+690$, and so on.

Comment: $$  \gcd( 42, 13 ) = ???    $$  

 $$ \frac{ 42 }{ 13 } = 3 +  \frac{ 3 }{ 13 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 13 }{ 3 } = 4 +  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3 }{ 1 } = 3 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:  
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 4 & & 3 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 42 }{ 13 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 42 \cdot 4 - 13 \cdot 13 = -1 $$

Comment: I like  continued fractions   for  Euclidean   $$  \gcd( 221, 169 ) = ???    $$  

 $$ \frac{ 221 }{ 169 } = 1 +  \frac{ 52 }{ 169 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 169 }{ 52 } = 3 +  \frac{ 13 }{ 52 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 52 }{ 13 } = 4 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 13 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:  
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 17 }{ 13 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 17 \cdot 3 - 13 \cdot 4 = -1 $$ 

 $$  \gcd( 221, 169 ) = 13  $$  
 $$ 221 \cdot 3 - 169 \cdot 4 = -13 $$

Comment: $$  \gcd( 13862, 10000 ) = ???    $$  

 $$ \frac{ 13862 }{ 10000 } = 1 +  \frac{ 3862 }{ 10000 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 10000 }{ 3862 } = 2 +  \frac{ 2276 }{ 3862 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 3862 }{ 2276 } = 1 +  \frac{ 1586 }{ 2276 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 2276 }{ 1586 } = 1 +  \frac{ 690 }{ 1586 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1586 }{ 690 } = 2 +  \frac{ 206 }{ 690 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 690 }{ 206 } = 3 +  \frac{ 72 }{ 206 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 206 }{ 72 } = 2 +  \frac{ 62 }{ 72 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 72 }{ 62 } = 1 +  \frac{ 10 }{ 62 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 62 }{ 10 } = 6 +  \frac{ 2 }{ 10 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 10 }{ 2 } = 5 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 2 } $$

Comment: $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 2 & & 1 & & 6 & & 5 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 18 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 61 }{ 44 }   & &   \frac{ 140 }{ 101 }   & &   \frac{ 201 }{ 145 }   & &   \frac{ 1346 }{ 971 }   & &   \frac{ 6931 }{ 5000 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 6931 \cdot 971 - 5000 \cdot 1346 = 1 $$ 

 $$  \gcd( 13862, 10000 ) = 2  $$  
 $$ 13862 \cdot 971 - 10000 \cdot 1346 = 2 $$

Comment: Thank you both very much. I learned quite a bit. Good stuff. I will continue looking for that old method. (Some of my books are in storage.) But now I have another keyword to look for in the indexes, "Euclidean algorithm."